# update line without erasing the content of the file with groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Here i want to update the content of a line in an existing file
But, when i run this code i get an empty file. How to solve this problem ?

here is the code source :

```
 def headerFilePattern = ~/^\d{1,2}-Header\.csv\u0024/
 final String PATH_SEPARATOR = "\\"
 String directoryPath = "C:\\directory"
 final String CHARACTER_ENCODING = "UTF-8"
 final String FILE_SEPARATOR = "="
 def linePattern = ~/\$\w.*=.*/
 def $_ = "\u0024"

 File directory = new File(directoryPath)

 println "Matching Files:"
 directory.eachFileRecurse({
     if (headerFilePattern.matcher(it.name).find()) {
         println "\t${it.name} (size ${it.size()})"
         File headerFile = new File(directoryPath + PATH_SEPARATOR + it.name);
         headerFile.withWriter { w ->
             headerFile.eachLine { line ->
                 if (linePattern.matcher(line)) {
                     def (key, value) = line.tokenize(FILE_SEPARATOR)
                     println "key : " + key
                     println "value : " + value
                     if (key == "${$_}countryCode") {
                         w << line.replaceAll( value, "World!!!21" )
                     }
                 }     
             }
         }
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

i create a copy of the original file to read from it and write in the original one then delete the copy. I don't know if this is the best solution for my problem :) !!!